# How to check for integer and less than or equal to 100 in an if/else statement

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner

I have an if/else statement with a scanner in the conditions, as well as an && statement checking for the input being 100 or less. It goes like this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

if(input.hasNextInt() && avgBefore <= 100) {
    avgBefore = input.nextInt();                
}
```

But if I put a number over 100 in, it still accepts it. Any help?

Comment: That's because you check `avgBefore` before you enter the value.

Comment: What are you asserting/checking on? `input.hasNextInt()` or `avgBefore`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're checking the value before you assign a new value to it. You need to assign the value from `nextInt()`, then check whether it's in range. For example:

```
if (input.hasNextInt()) {
    int candidate = input.nextInt();
    if (candidate <= 100) {
        avgBefore = candidate;
    } else {
        // Whatever you want to do on invalid input
    }
}
```

That's assuming you want to avoid assigning invalid values to `avgBefore`. If that's not an issue, you can use:

```
if (input.hasNextInt()) {
    avgBefore = input.nextInt();
    if (avgBefore > 100) {
        // Whatever you want to do on invalid input
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, totally makes sense. Sorry, I've been learning java for only about 6 months. This help a lot.

Comment: in the second lot of code shouldnt that if statement say avgBefore > 100? seeing as candidate is not defined? @Jon Skeet

Comment: @DanielGee: Yes, absolutely - typo, sorry.

Comment: @JonSkeet never thought I would correct the #1 user on SO!

Comment: @DanielGee: *Everyone* makes mistakes. Never be scared about correcting someone just because they're well known. Be *careful* when correcting someone whether they're well known or not, however.

Answer (score 0):

As already said, you must assign the value and then check if is <= 100. A less readable but one-liner solution can be:

```
if(input.hasNextInt() && (avgBefore = input.nextInt()) <= 100) { // assign the value and immediately test if is <= 100
    // whatever you want to do with `avgBefore`
}
```